# CRM - Can I access the running workflow

Tags: javascript, sdk, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to access the workflow that running on the current record to check is it in waiting condition or running.
I want to access it using JavaScript code.

for example, I have a workflow that runs on the Case entity, I want to monitor it in javascript which means that I find the current status of this workflow,
successful, waiting , error.

Can i do that or it is not applicable.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Your question is far too vague..

Comment: Updated, I hope it be clear now

Comment: you should include the version of CRM you are working on as that impacts the answer.  Assuming 2011 or later, you can use OData, prior to that, you have to use SOAP

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it.  Use OData and query against the WorkflowLogSet.  You can query based on status or record id or both.  Using the restkit, it would look something like this:

```
var currentCase = Xrm.Page.data.getId();
var filter = 'RegardingObjectId/Id eq ' + currentCase + '&Status/Value eq 2' //<-- or whatever statuses you want
CRMRestKit.ByQuery('WorkflowLog',[columnset],filter).done(function(){
    //Do what you want with these items
}).fail(function(){ alert("failed to retrieve workflow");});
```